# Plot Multiple Series from Related Table in One Chart

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, popup, chart, relates, infowindow

I'm trying to figure out how to plot multiple line series/charts in one chart in a popup window from attributes in a related table using the Javascript API. It seems like the only way to create a chart from a related table is using the esri [PopupTemplate](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/popuptemplate.html). I have successfully created two separate charts in the popup, but I want to plot them in the same chart for comparison. Can I use dojox.charting and an info window with related tables? I couldn't get something like "graphic.attributes.relationships/0/*field*" to work. That seems like the route I need to take to create the chart I want, but I am not finding any information regarding related tables.

I'm plotting average monthly minimum and maximum temperatures (related table) for weather observation stations. This is the look I'm going for (red line for average maximum temperature, blue line for average minimum temperature):

[image]

Comment: To pursue this further can you tell us what version of the ArcGIS API for JavaScript you are using and include a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck, please?